# Is it possible to do two DML operations in a single trigger?

Tags: trigger, dml

I have a custom object called `Junction__c` with lookups to `Custom__c`, and `Case`. In the data model, `Custom__c` is also a child of `Case`.

There is a validation rule to ensure that any `Custom__c` record being related to a `Junction__c` record is actually a child of the related `Case` record referenced on the `Junction__c` record.

This is creating an issue in one of my triggers. The trigger is creating a new child `Case` record, and establishing links to both `Custom__c` and `Case`, but is throwing a validation rule error. The issue is because the record has not yet been inserted, and so `Case` is `null`.

How do I work around this? Is there a way to insert the case, retrieve it, and then update it, i.e. do two DML operations in a single trigger?

Comment: Yes, the record doesn't have to be "fully inserted" to get an Id for it. You simply need to insert the case (this will return an Id you can use), then insert the Custom__c (which you'll get another Id you can use), and finally link everything together. However, without specifically seeing your code, we can't really tell where you went wrong. It's probably just the wrong order of operations or something.

Comment: Shouldn't the validation rule only apply when relating a Custom__c record to a Junction__c record?  It sounds like that's not what's happening here.